# Torque and Moment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

pole vaulter holding a vaulting pole parallel to the ground. the pole is 5 metres long. vaulter grips pole with right hand 10 cm from the top end of the pole and with his left hand 1 metre from the top end of the pole. pole is 2.5kg, how large are the forces exerted on the pole for it to maintain in this position, assuming the vaulter exerts only vertical (up or down) forces on the horizontal pole and that the center of gravity of the pole is located at the center of its length

Comment: the ans: right hand exerts 40.9N downward force on pole, left hand exerts 65.4N upward force

Answer (score 1):

Without providing a numerical answer to your question, to do so would help nobody:

It would help to first draw a 'free-body-diagram', doing so will help you visualise the forces acting on the pole.

- You need to calculate the moment at the hand 1m from the end, this is your pivot, from the force exerted by the mass of the pole.
- Calculate the force required at the other hand to counter the moment at the pivoting hand.
- The remaining force, the reaction at the pivot in the upward direction will be the sum of all downward forces. This gives you an equilibrium state